# PDO too many connections using factory pattern for connection PHP

Tags: php, pdo, factory-pattern

After some help from teresko, i have managed to implement the factory design method in order to connect to my database only once (thats what i thought), but now im recieving this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections' in

It then goes on to describe about 8 different connections in different places. How comes im making so many connections?

Here is my factory class:

```
namespace App\Core;

class structureFactory
{
    protected $provider = null;
    protected $connection = null;

    public function __construct( callable $provider )
    {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }

    public function create( $name)
    {
        if ( $this->connection === null )
        {
            $this->connection = call_user_func( $this->provider );
        }
        return new $name( $this->connection );
    }
}
```

And because i only need the connections in my model classes i have created a baseModel class which gets the database connection from structureFactory and looks like this:

```
namespace App\Core\Models;

use App\Core\structureFactory as SF;

abstract class baseModel {

    public $getConnection;
    protected function getAdapter() {

        $this->getConnection = function() {

            $m_rdbms = 'mysql';
            $m_host = 'localhost';
            $m_db_name = 'cvcms';
            $m_host_name = $m_rdbms . ':host=' . $m_host. ';dbname=' . $m_db_name;
            $m_uname = 'root';
            $m_pwd ='';

            $instance = new \PDO($m_host_name, $m_uname, $m_pwd);
            $instance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $instance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            return $instance;
        };

        $factory = new SF($this->getConnection);
        return $factory->create('App\\Core\\Models\\DAL');
    }

}
```

So this basically makes a new SF with the Connection made in getConnection function, and then returns a new DAL.

Here is an example of my controller which makes a new DAL and calls the function safeQuery :

```
namespace App\Frontend\Base\Index;

use App\Frontend\Base\baseController as base;
use App\Core\Models\DAL as DAL;

class indexController extends base{

public $data;

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function indexMethod(){
    $query = "SELECT site_data FROM site_data WHERE site_data = :name;";
    $args = array(":name" => 'site_name');
    $this->data = new DAL;
    $this->data = $this->data->safeQuery($query,$args);
}

function render(){

    //Render the index template/view parsing the data acquired from model.
}

}
```

And in my DAL construct i store the connection in a local variable like so by gettting it from the baseModel:

```
use App\Core\Models\baseModel as BM;

class DAL extends BM {

private $c_arr_database_connection_messages;
private $c_obj_pdo;
private $c_obj_stmt;

public function __construct() {
    $this->c_arr_database_connection_messages = array();
    $this->c_obj_pdo = $this->getAdapter();
    echo $this->c_obj_pdo;
    $this->c_obj_stmt = null;
}

...

}
```

Can you guys help me work out where im going wrong please?

Cheers
Tom

Comment: `$this->connection` will always be `null` in `App\Core\structureFactory` thus creating a new PDO object in each model as you instantiating a new `structureFactory`

Comment: Ok, so how would i correct this Ian? Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `structureFactory` could look something like this.

```
namespace App\Core;

class structureFactory
{
    protected $connection;

    public function getConnection() 
    {
        if (!$this->connection) {
            $this->connection = new PDO('dsn');
        }
        return $this->connection;
    }
}



namespace App\Core\Models;

use App\Core\structureFactory as structureFactory;

abstract class baseModel {

    protected $factory;

    public function __construct(structureFactory $factory) 
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    protected function getAdapter() {
        return $this->factory->getConnection();
    }

} 



use App\Core\Models\baseModel as BM;

class DAL extends BM {

    private $c_arr_database_connection_messages;
    private $c_obj_pdo;
    private $c_obj_stmt;

    public function __construct(App\Core\structureFactory $factory) {
        parent::__construct($factory);

        $this->c_arr_database_connection_messages = array();
        $this->c_obj_pdo = $this->getAdapter();
        echo $this->c_obj_pdo;
        $this->c_obj_stmt = null;
    }

...

}
```

Comment: I was doing osmething similar before but teresko seemed to think it was a rough singleton antipattern.. any comments?

Comment: You could inject `structureFactory` into your models and construct your parent.

Comment: Exactly that. So where your instantiate your Models, pass it the `structureFactory`, add a constructor to your baseModel and pass the `structureFactory` instance to it.

Comment: I have tried imlplementing the above code to see if i can get it to simply work. In the baseModel i shange the parameter passed to the constructor so SF $factory as if i used structure Factory it thre an error, and it seems to have now recognised it, except now in the getAdapter function when i try to use the function ->getConnection i get an error saying the method is not found in structureFactory, which it clearly is, am i missing something? Cheers

Comment: Ok, i was being stupid! after following the flow of the app i realised the sf wasnt even getting passed, what a muppet! Thanks for your help, i now have a single connection to the DB!